# Should I use a 301 Redirect when tracking outgoing clicks?

Tags: http, redirect, tracking, http-status-code-301

I currently track outgoing clicks on my site by routing the user through a `track.php` file.  This file records the click, then redirects the user.  I assume that this causes problems for  search engines trying to follow my outgoing links.

If I do a 301 redirect from my `track.php` file ( after recording the click ), will this allow search engines to properly follow my outgoing links, even though they route through my `track.php` file?

Are there problems with this method?  Will this look weird to search engines and cause me other unforeseen problems?

Comment: you never know what search engines will consider a red flag. but here's something interesting. Google is tracking outbound clicks, and they're doing it with 200 and javascript. so go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where I read this, but someone else presented a question like this a while back. When most search engine crawlers hit your site, they different request headers than a normal user accessing your website from a browser. You could potentially get the USER_AGENT in PHP and display regular outgoing links if a spider hits your website and links to  track.php if its actually a user accessing the website.

Just a thought.

Comment: of course you can "trick" the crawlers (that's actually one of the black hat SEO tricks). but then again, if google finds out that you pull such tricks - your site could get banned. I don't think it's worth it.